# Android Instant App with React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

I'm a Native Android Developer, but for now, I join a team who build an app using React-Native.

My job is to refactor the previous app that I had built using React-Native. My previous app support Instant-App and Deeplink using Firebase Dynamic link.

**If I rebuild this app using React native, is that possible? an *Instant App* and a *Deeplink*?**

I have do some research in google, but I do not have any great example or explanation on this things.

Answer (score 1):

Deeplink yes, we are currently doing it.  Not sure about instant app, found your question by asking same question